# Pycharm is not recognising unfilled parameters

Tags: python, pycharm

Pycharm inspection not warning about missing parameters if the method is imported indirectly from another file:

```
# Class1.py:
from Class2 import *
def foo_a(a:Class2)
   a.b.foo()  #Pycharm does not warn here. 

# Class2.py:
from Class3 import *
Class2:
   __init__(self):
      self.b=Class3()

# Class3.py
Class3:
    __init__(self):
        pass
    def foo(self,a,b):
        pass
```

I would like to be warned in those situations, what to do?

Comment: Not sure if its that you just have not written it out as it exists in your code, but your import of the foo function just will not work as written above. When you say import File2 , a function in File2.py would have to be accessed like `File2.foo()`

Comment: What do you mean by "method is imported indirectly"? Do note that `import File2` doesn't load `foo` into the current scope. Using `foo` as you are in the example would raise a `NameError`.

Comment: Sorry correcting

Answer (score 1):

You must import as `from File2 import foo`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you import the functions directly it will.

```
# File1.py
from File2 import foo

# File2.py
from File3 import foo
```

Comment: nesaboz beat me to it but that's the idea.